Module imported into different scopes, do they both refer to the same object?
At the Spyder console (the REPL), I issue import matplotlib.pyplot as plt.  It is the topmost namespace, i.e., corresponding  to globals().
In a Spyder startup file, I define a function to raise figure windows to the top.
def TKraiseCFG( FigID = None ):

   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   # The rest is just context
   #-------------------------
   # Assigning to plt unnecessary if
   # imported plt is same object as in
   # caller's scope
   plt = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals['plt'] # plt=globals()['plt']
      # https://stackoverflow.com/a/78732915
   if FigID is not None: plt.figure( FigID )
   cfm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
   cfm.window.attributes('-topmost', True)
   cfm.window.attributes('-topmost', False)
   return cfm

Does the plt in TKraiseCFG() refer to the same object as plt at the REPL?
Further context (not the main question):  I can't imagine a console/REPL (or even multiple consoles) using more than one matplotlib.pyplot.  But I'm just getting to know Python, so I could be wrong.  For the case of a single common matplotlib.pyplot, however, I'm seeking a way to have it accessible to all scopes so that I can write convenience/utility functions like TKraiseCFG() (which is just cobbled together after reading various pages, weeks ago).  Unfortunately, my current method requires that code invoking TKraiseCFG() contain a variable specifically named plt referencing matplotlib.pyplot.

In general, yes.  Imports are cached in sys.modules and subsequent imports will just return the already loaded module.  There are some edge cases where modules can accidentally be imported under two different identities, but I don't think they apply here.


Does the plt in TKraiseCFG() refer to the same object as plt at the REPL?

Yes it is the same object. Although I couldn't find matplotlib documentation that states this clearly.
You can test that the plt objects point to the same instance with the is operator like this:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test_plt_equivalence():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt2  
    print(plt2 is plt) # This will print True if plt and plt2 are the same object
    
test_plt_equivalence()


Thanks!  I found that using id(plt) in both the caller and in TKraiseCFG() also confirms that both modules are the same.

The first time you import a module, it goes into a cache.  Every time after that, no matter where you import it from, you get the same module object back from the cache.  It has nothing to do with matplotlib itself, it's how the Python module system works.

@ Mark Ransom: Understood, thanks.
